# Creating a shape file: ggplot2

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2

I am attempting to create my own quasi-shapefile and supply it to ggplot2.  I have done this using premade map data from the maps package.  I am unable to create a shapefile that plots all pieces.

I was hoping for all id areas to be plotted but it appears I have made an error but I don't understand how or where.  Here is the current plot with the pieces 1 through 8 missing.

How can I get these missing pieces to plot.  Here's the data:

```
space.manikin.shape <- structure(list(x = c(0.4, 0.4, 0.6, 0.6, 0.35, 0.4, 0.6, 0.65, 
    0.6, 0.65, 0.65, 0.6, 0.4, 0.35, 0.65, 0.6, 0.35, 0.35, 0.4, 
    0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.65, 0.65, 0.73, 0.73, 0.65, 
    0.65, 0.73, 0.73, 0.6, 0.6, 0.73, 0.73, 0.65, 0.65, 0.4, 0.4, 
    0.6, 0.6, 0.27, 0.27, 0.4, 0.4, 0.35, 0.35, 0.27, 0.27, 0.35, 
    0.35, 0.27, 0.27, 0.35, 0.35, 0.4, 0.4, 0.35, 0.35, 0.65, 0.65, 
    0.65, 0.65, 0.73, 0.73, 1, 1, 0.73, 0.73, 1, 1, 0.65, 0.65, 1, 
    1, 0.73, 0.73, 0.35, 0.35, 0.65, 0.65, 0, 0, 0.35, 0.35, 0.27, 
    0.27, 0, 0, 0.27, 0.27, 0, 0, 0.27, 0.27, 0.35, 0.35), y = c(0.67, 
    0.525, 0.525, 0.67, 0.75, 0.67, 0.67, 0.75, 0.525, 0.475, 0.75, 
    0.67, 0.525, 0.475, 0.475, 0.525, 0.75, 0.475, 0.525, 0.67, 0.87, 
    0.75, 0.75, 0.87, 0.87, 0.75, 0.75, 0.67, 0.67, 0.87, 0.67, 0.525, 
    0.525, 0.67, 0.475, 0.28, 0.28, 0.525, 0.525, 0.475, 0.475, 0.28, 
    0.28, 0.475, 0.525, 0.28, 0.28, 0.475, 0.475, 0.525, 0.67, 0.525, 
    0.525, 0.67, 0.87, 0.67, 0.67, 0.75, 0.75, 0.87, 1, 0.87, 0.87, 
    1, 1, 0.87, 0.87, 0.75, 0.75, 1, 0.75, 0.475, 0.475, 0.75, 0.28, 
    0, 0, 0.475, 0.475, 0.28, 0.28, 0, 0, 0.28, 0.475, 0, 0, 0.28, 
    0.28, 0.475, 0.75, 0.475, 0.475, 0.75, 1, 0.75, 0.75, 0.87, 0.87, 
    1), id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
    13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
    15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
    18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
    20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L), .Label = c("01", "02", "03", 
    "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", 
    "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21"), class = "factor"), 
        order = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
        1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
        4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 
        3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
        4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 
        3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
        4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L)), .Names = c("x", 
    "y", "id", "order"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -100L))

centers <- data.frame(
    id = 1:21,
    center.x=c(.5, .5, .625, .5, .375, .5, .66, .69, .66, .5, .34, .31, 
        .34, .5, .79, .815, .79, .5, .16, .135, .16),
    center.y=c(.597, .71, .5975, .5, .5975, .82, .81, .6475, .39, .3775, .39, 
        .6475, .81, .935, .89, .6025, .19, .14, .19, .6025, .89)
)

library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(png)

ggplot(centers) + geom_map(aes(map_id = id), map = space.manikin.shape, colour="white") +
    expand_limits(space.manikin.shape) +
    geom_text(data=centers, aes(center.x, center.y, label = id), color="grey60")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what `list_df2df` does or in what package it is.

If I use my own interpretation using `polygon`, the polygons look correct. Also, as you're missing polygons 1:9, so I suspect something goes wrong in the matching of polygon and center ids. The polygons are named `01`, `02` etc. while the center ids are named `1`, `2` etc. Perhaps this causes your problem.

Example with `polygon`:

```
plot(0:1,0:1,type='n', ann=F, axes=T)
for (i in 1:length(dat)){
  polygon(x=dat[[i]]$x, y=dat[[i]]$y, col=2)
  text(x=centers[i,'center.x'], y=centers[i,'center.y'], labels=i)
}
# ... nothing wrong with polygon or center coordinates
```

[image]

Comment: You're comments were spot on.  I had `01, 02, 03, ..., 09` for one data set and `1, 2, 3,..., 9` for the other.